# Kendo Unbound Column

Tags: vb.net, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like to add a custom column to this grid and i tried the template method as in the code below but the code does not even compile and i get thrown an error which i have provided below as well. I want to create a custom column inside the kendo grid and then have a clickable link inside that column which call a javascript function. Is it possible?

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Gatekeeper.SystemGroupMembers)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "DisplayMembers"
End Code

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) _
        .Name("SystemGroupMembers") _
        .Columns(Sub(c)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.Name)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.Class)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.ParentName)
                     c.Template(@<text>blah</text>).Title("blah")
                 End Sub) _
.Sortable() _
.DataSource(Sub(c)
                c.Ajax() _
                .ServerOperation(False)
            End Sub)
)

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "DisplayGroups")
</div>
```

Error:

```
Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.

Source Error:

Line 8:              .Name("SystemGroupMembers") _
Line 9:              .Columns(Sub(c)
Line 10:                             c.Template(@<text>Click here</text>)
Line 11:                              c.Bound(Function(p) p.Name)
Line 12:                              c.Bound(Function(p) p.Class)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use ClientTemplate instead of Template?

Comment: this is what i get when i try ClientTemplate: 
Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'ClientTemplate' is not a member of 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridColumnFactory(Of Gatekeeper.SystemGroupMembers)'.

Source Error:

Comment: I tried to solve this problem. Please take a look at my answer below. Regards

Answer (score 0):

As I see this code, the problem is you are defining a model for your view and then you are also linking this model to kendo grid and this is not possible. This should be two separate models. I guess you don't even need a model for a view that is rendering the grid. You also haven't defined read action in DataSource definition.
I'm not `vb.net` developer but I would try to do this in this way. Please correct me if my vb syntax is wrong:

```
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "DisplayMembers"
End Code

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of Gatekeeper.SystemGroupMembers) _
        .Name("SystemGroupMembers") _
        .Columns(Sub(c)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.Name)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.Class)
                     c.Bound(Function(p) p.ParentName)
                     c.Template(@<text>blah</text>).Title("blah")
                 End Sub) _
.Sortable() _
.DataSource(Sub(c)
                c.Ajax() _
              .Read(Function(read) read.Action("SomeAction", "YourController")) _
                .ServerOperation(False)
            End Sub)
)

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "DisplayGroups")
</div>
```

Also take a look at this link:

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/vb#grid

Comment: hmm there is nothing different you are doing here from what i am doing. instead of the read function i am reading the data off the model object which is passed from the controller to the view and grid is bound to that IEnumerable(of Model) object.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that your approach is going to work because this is not the way Kendo grid works. You can also check this: https://www.telerik.com/forums/connecting-grid-to-collection-in-model

Comment: my grid works. i want to add the extra unbound column that was the only issue.